# putting a code-block-like control from App Inventor in desktop app

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to make a simple program that allows you to click and drag an item from one window, a child window, to another, the parent window. It's going to be a game level editor of sorts that I'm working on for a video game I need for a school project. I have months to do it, so I'm in no rush.

The thing I'm curious about is how I'll get an item from the child window to the parent window during runtime. I can have buttons in the child window that place objects in the parent window. That was my original idea - so having the Drag and Drop functionality isn't exactly necessary. I just want to know if I can do that with images, in a format similar to App Inventor - how it writes code in the background while you fiddle around with the building window, placing various blocks down. My version would be exactly like App Inventor, but it's in a desktop application and there are no words, only pictures.

[image]

Does WINAPI have a control like that already built in? If so, I would love to know the name or where to find information about it. I'm just not sure how to begin to search for that, except for this site.

My original idea was to use picturebox controls, but I'd either have to litter the entire window with them and allow the user to click and drag them to "move" them around while it sets the image to one or the other picturebox, while in the background setting the code automatically, or something else. Either way, I'm sure it's possible, but I really doubt that's the way I want to go.

Comment: Drag&Drop between windows is implemented using the `IDragSource` and `IDropTarget` interfaces with the `RegisterDragDrop()` and `DoDragDrop()` functions. The source window creates an `IDataObject` to represent the item(s) be dragged, and passes that to `DoDragDrop()` along with its `IDragSource`. The target window's `IDropTarget` receives the `IDataObject` and can extract the items from it. `IDragSourceHelper/2` and `IDropTargetHelper` can optionally be implemented to display custom images during dragging

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I was looking to just use buttons instead. There are a lot of things that the user will be able to put in the main window, and many instances of each, so the shorter the code can be the better. I was just hoping and wondering if there was anything I could do similar to AppInventor's code block controls. The Drag and Drop thing was just added as an alternative to buttons, which isn't the main thing I'm asking.  Still, thanks for getting back to me!

Comment: AppInventor is a 3rd party app that many people here likely have not heard of (I haven't). It would help if you could post screenshots or a video/GIF of the functionality you want to replicate. What problem are you having with clicking a button in one window that adds an item in another window? That is a pretty basic operation to perform even with core Win32 UI controls. You need to provide more details about your issue, or your question is likely to get closed as off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Remy. I went to the site and found what I was talking about and took a screenshot, then edited the relevant information to it, as well as reposted my question onto it, refined. https://imgur.com/a/ARfKE

Comment: That AppInventor UI is clearly not a multi-window UI, so dragging objects around is probably pretty simple for it to do. [AppInventor is open source](http://appinventor.mit.edu/appinventor-sources/), so feel free to see how they actually implemented it. But you haven't answered my question yet. What actual problem are you having in implementing your goal? Clicking a button to add something in another window is not difficult to do, so what are you hung up on exactly? You could use a PictureBox for your controls, but I would use a custom-drawn control for better performance, custom shapes, etc.

Comment: Working with picturebox controls in the past have been rather restricting. I must say though, that I've never worked with them in C++, only with Visual Basic. Are you actually able to allow the user to click a picture in a picture box, then take that picture and move it around according to where the user's cursor is, and then leave it where the cursor rests once the user clicks again? And can I get the x and y of where it is located? My hang up is that I don't understand how I will implement this system, not that I can't. I don't have the knowledge, but I have the ability. Character limitsSuck

Comment: The problem with that though, is that this program is a level editing program for a game, and must not only be able to do this picture thing, but also scroll to the right and back to the left. I currently have a group box set up, so multiple picture boxes would allow me to do that, but if it's just one, I doubt it'll work correctly.

Comment: That doesn't change what I said. I would still create a custom drawn control for the pictures (that way, you can load a given bitmap in memory once and share it across all controls that need it), and simply place them on a scrollable parent window. But even if you use a separate PictureBox for each image, that's fine too (at the cost of more memory used).

Comment: As for dragging, that is easy if it is within a single parent window. `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` can save the current mouse position, `WM_MOUSEMOVE` can move the image relative to the last mouse position while the mouse is held down, and `WM_LBUTTONUP` can finalize the drag. Dragging over parent window boundaries is a bit harder. I would have `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` set a flag, `WM_MOUSEMOVE` create a floating window that shows the same image if the flag is set, and then move that window around, and then `WM_LBUTTONUP` applies the image to the new parent window and destroy the floating window.

Comment: I'll look into that. That sounds pretty feasible. I'm gonna learn all of that and see if it'll work out for me.Thank you for all the help